# Manipulating C-style strings

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I need to write a function that modifies a C-string as follows:

```
void foo(const char* input, ostream& fout);
//foo("test", std::cout) -> "test est st t "
//foo("hi_world", std::cout) -> "hi_world i_world world orld rld ld d "
```

The function just prints the string and removes the first character each time. The function does not print if the character removed is an underscore.

Here is what I have so far:

```
void foo(const char* input, ostream& fout) {
    char * answer;

    while(*input) {
        if(*input == '_') {
            //somehow do nothing
        }
        if(input > input[0] {
            fout << *input+1
        }
        else {
            fout << *input << " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing to increment the pointer (`++input:`) in that loop. Also a closing brace `}` is missing at the end of that function.

Comment: `'_'` Moooooooom! His code is staring at me again!

Comment: `if (input > input[0])` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my answer because I misread the question the first time, but I think this will do what you're looking for.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

void foo(const char* input, std::ostream& fout) {
    char* answer;

   for(int n = 0; n < strlen(input); n++){
       answer = (char*)&input[n];

       while (*answer){

            if (*answer != '_') {
                fout << *answer;
            }
            
            answer++;
        }

       fout << " ";
   }

   fout << "\n"; // Assuming you want a newline at the end.
}


int main(){
    const char* phrase = "test\0";
    const char* phrase2 = "hi_world\0";
    
    foo(phrase, std::cout);
    foo(phrase2, std::cout);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Running this produced the following output.

```
$ ./answer 
test est st t 
hiworld iworld world world orld rld ld d
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `input` each time through the loop to change the starting index of the string.

Use `continue;` to skip the iteration if the first character is `_`.

To print the string, use `fout << input`. `fout << *input` will just print one character, not the whole string.

```
void foo(const char* input, ostream& fout) {
    for(; *input; input++) {
        if(input[0] == '_') {
            continue;
        }
        fout << input << " ";
    }
}
```